# how to open .pdf files in safari from my web view app

Tags: ios

I have my web app staying in the one web view and have it opening links outside of the domain in safari. What i need to do is add .pdf files that are in the domain to open in safari. as of now they open in the web view and there is no navigation to get back out of it so you have to force quite the app and relaunch.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rbc.samkingmedia.com"]]];
    _webView.delegate = self;
    [_webView addSubview:activityind];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)loading {
    if (!_webView.loading)
        [activityind stopAnimating];
    else
        [activityind startAnimating];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {


    //  open External Links (not beginning with www.playbuzz.org/ in Safari.app
    if (
        (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) &&
        ( ![[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"http://rbc.samkingmedia.com/"])
        ) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }

    //open Internal links in uiwebview
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add navigation you should use SFSafariViewController

its an example in swift code

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: self.urlString)!, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

you can find more information in 
[this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-getting-started-with-sfsafariviewcontroller--cms-24260) tutorial